# Reclassifying an "Add Field" with If/Else statement based on multiple fields

Tags: python, if-statement, arcmap

I am just too new to Python to figure it out myself. Here goes:

I have a table of Traffic Count data with: Street Location | Direction | Dir__NB_or | Dir_SB_or and I was attempting to write a reclassification into the new field of Count.

What I am looking for is a script to say: "*if direction is N or E, insert Dir__NB_or into field Count"*

Is what I have, (probably horrific) but I would appreciate any help you can provide!

```
Reclass (Dir__NB_or , Dir_SB_or, Direction):
    if (Direction == "N"):
           return Dir__NB_or
    elif (Direction == "S"):
            return Dir_SB_or
    elif (Direction == "E"):
            return Dir__NB_or
    elif (Direction == "W"):
            return Dir_SB_or
    else:
            return "0000"

Count = Reclass ( !Dir__NB_or! , !Dir_SB_or!, !Direction! )
```

Edit: I should mention I am using ESRI's ArcMap and Field Calculator for this task.

Comment: What syntaxes are these !Dir__NB_or!?

Comment: Sorry, new to this forum. Those are the titles of the field I was given... Not great I know.
edit: DIr_NB_or holds the traffic count data that I wan to put into the new field "Count" based on the field Direction.

Comment: I guess you want `'Dir__NB_or`' and so on.

Comment: Yes, basically if the field Direction is "N" or "E" I want to pull the data from field Dir_NB_or, and opposite if the direction is "S" or "W". Sorry I should mention I am using ArcMap and Field Calculator

Comment: Oh, sorry I've no idea about ArcMap and Field Calculator.

Comment: That shouldn't matter too much. The data is all in the same table, I am just attempting to move it from Field A(Dir_NB_or) to Field B(Count) based on the qualifier of Field C(Direction).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it from attribute table field calculator, mark check on Show Codeblock in attribute table Field Calculator

type this in the Pre-logic Script Code:

```
def pFunction(Direction,DirNB,DirSB):
  if (Direction == "N") or (Direction == "E"):
    return DirNB
  elif (Direction == "W") or (Direction == "S"):
    return DirSB
  else:
    return 00
```

and this in lower textbox

```
pFunction(!Direction!,!Dir__NB_or!,!Dir_SB_or!)
```

Comment: That seems to have worked, but I am getting an error when running it saying that the return line  of DirNB is not defined..

Answer (score 0):

Just combine your if conditions. I did not understand what you mean by "if direction is N or E, **insert** Dir__NB_or **into field Count**" the bold terms

```
if (Direction == "N") or (Direction == "E"):
    return Dir__NB_or
elif (Direction == "S") or (Direction == "W"):
    return Dir_SB_or
else:
    return "0000"
```

Comment: Dir_NB_or_(EB) is what it should be and is numerical data about traffic, and what I was trying to write is a code that will read from the field "Direction" and automatically pull the data from either "Dir_NB_or"(EB) or "Dir_SB_or"(WB) to fill the field "Count"